# Assign resourceId to Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-resources

As I Know the following thing.

> A resource ID is a 32 bit number of the form: PPTTNNNN. PP is the
> package the resource is for; TT is the type of the resource; NNNN is
> the name of the resource in that type. For applications resources, PP
> is always 0x7f.

**Example :**

these resource files handled by aapt in this order:

```
layout/main.xml
drawable/icon.xml
layout/listitem.xml
```

The first type we see is `layout` so that is given `TT == 1`. The first name under that type is "main" so that is given `NNNN == 1`. The final resource ID is `0x7f010001`.

Next we see `drawable` so that is given `TT == 2`. The first name for that type is "icon" so that gets `NNNN == 1`. The final resource ID is `0x7f020001`.

Last we see another `layout` which has `TT == 1` as before. This has a new name `listitem` so that gets the next value `NNNN == 2`. The final resource ID is `0x7f010002`.

**Question :**

But Recently I see some of the layout file are assign ID by below way.

**java code**

```
 this.f5160k = (ImageView) findViewById(2131755224);
 this.f5163n = findViewById(2131755219);
 this.f5162m = (LinearLayout) findViewById(2131755223);
 this.f5161l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(2131755220);
 this.f5158i = (GridView) findViewById(2131755222);
```

As the first part `this.f5160k` is Declartion as i know but what is this format `2131755224`. can one Anyone give me Suggestion or Knowledge. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2131755224` is the decimal representation of `0x7F1000D8`

In the code that you shared, developer decided to hardcoded the decimal number instead of using the hexadecimal format. However, both has the same value and are pointing to same resourceID.

You can choose to use `2131755224` or `0x7F1000D8`.

In R.java, you can find the IDs in hexadecimal format.

Comment: this `2131755224` is manually generate or we have make like `public.xml` file.

Comment: Since the value is hardcoded, you have to use public.xml. This way, value won't change. R.java is automatically generated and IDs constantly changes (and it is impossible to let them hardcoded in source code). So, in public.xml you can define the ID in hexa format and use the hexa or decimal format in java files... There's no difference since they are different representation but of the same number (or same ID in this case).

Answer (score 3):

These large numbers are just the decimal representation of numbers of format `0x7f..` (which is hexadecimal by the way).

```
 long n = 2131755224;
 System.out.println(Long.toHexString(n));
```

Output: `7f1000d8`

`2131755224 == 0x7F1000D8` will return `true`.